# regex: match all characteres between 2 words, returns strange output

Tags: python, regex

in this text:

```
"IPAddress":"10.0.0.18","PolicerID":"","IPAddress":"","PolicerID":""
```

I want to catch all ips, in this example are 10.0.0.18 and emptystring

I tried to use this regex:

> (?<="IPAddress":")(.*?)(?=")

which returns me 10.0.0.18 and ",
it took the first " from PolicerID instead of the last " in IPAddress.

Can you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Your sample text is leading me to believe there is a much easier way to do this. Can you post a bit more of your sample data?

Comment: it's not a regular json if that what you think. more code is just some more parameteres that I prefer not to share

Comment: Yeah... it's not regular JSON, but if you add `{` and `}` it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can keep it simple and just use a capturing group:

```
>>> str = r'"IPAddress":"10.0.0.18","PolicerID":"","IPAddress":"","PolicerID":""'
>>> print re.findall(r'"IPAddress":"([^"]*)', str)
['10.0.0.18', '']
>>>
```

However if you have to use lookbehind assertion then use this regex:

```
(?<="IPAddress":")([^"]*)
```

`([^"]*)` is a **negated pattern** to match 0 or more of any character that is not a double quote.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/dU9qI1/1)

Answer (score 0):

If you want all IPs in that text I would suggest this regex

```
[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+){3}
```